# google calendar api - listener for onclick on calendar events

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I am creating a google calendar widget using the javascript client. I want to attach a listener for the "onclick" of calendar events. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to listen for click events in the Calendar UI.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is there any hack that I can use? I tried looking through the calendar html source, and could see the div that held the event bubble. I will attach an on-click listener to it and try.